# Export Folder in RCP Eclipse Application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-pde

I am quite new to eclipse e4 rcp application development.
While exporting application I want one of folders in project root to be in export.
I checked folder "config" in build.properties, still i am unable to see that folder in the final export.

Here is my build.properties

```
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = META-INF/,\
               .,\
               Application.e4xmi,\
               bin/,\
               log4j.xml,\
               plugin.xml,\
               splash.bmp,\
               config/,\
               css/,\
               icons/,\
               lib/
\
               lib/log4j-api-2.3.jar,\
               lib/log4j-core-2.3.jar
source.. = src/
jars.compile.order = .
```

As someone suggested here previously, I also put
    Eclipse-BundleShape: dir
in MANIFEST.MF but still "config" folder doesnt appear. Any help will be appricitaed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Folder is missing at the root folder or inside plugin->yourplugin-name

Comment: @SumitSingh will you please elaborate?

Comment: means you are expecting your folder on root level(means eclipse folder) or inside root folder there is one folder plugins inside plugin you have one jar file or a folder for your plugin.

Comment: Where are you looking for the folder?

Comment: @greg-449 under the folder where application is exported.

Comment: Everything in the build.properties becomes part of the plugin in the plugins directory. If you want to add to the application folder read [Adding files to the root of a build](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Fpde_rootfiles.htm)

Comment: @neil In build tab , under the Manifest.mf check the folders you want to export.

Comment: @abdul, I created a separate feature for exporting the folders using rootfiles. Thanks for your response anyway :)

Comment: Yeah that is the other alternative...